# Did Maxwell invent the math to describe the ideas of electromagnetism?

Tags: history, mathematics, maxwell-equations

Did he invent surface and line integrals, or did they already exist when he formulated his equations. If they did, already exist, how did they come about in pure math?

Comment: Maxwell was not solely responsible for vector calculus, the formalism was developed before his treatise by Gibbs and Heaviside, as well as others.

Comment: Also, if you read his treatise, most of the modern notation is absent. No $\nabla \times \vec{E}$ type stuff, so it's a lot more verbose.

Comment: Wasn't Ampère cast Farady's results in mathematical form. Poisson was a real mathematical physicist, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Maxwell did not invent surface or line integrals.  See [History of Stokes' Theorem](http://www.ingelec.uns.edu.ar/asnl/Materiales/Cap03Extras/Stokes-Katz.pdf), which explains surface integrals were in use earlier.